# How to call two separate images from Matrix field

Tags: assets

I'm new to Craft and using Matrix fields.

I've got a matrix field called `imageDouble` with two child fields called `firstImage` and `secondImage`.

The template code I have is returning a 500 error. I want it to display `firstImage` and `secondImage` each in their own separate div. Any help with my structure here?

```
{% for block in entry.body %}

    {% if block.type == "text" %}

        <div class="row text detail">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                <p>{{ block.textContent }}</p>

            </div>

        </div>

    {% elseif block.type == "imageDouble" %}

        {% set image = block.image.first() %}

            {% if image %}

            <div class="row imageDouble detail">

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">

                    <img src="{{ firstImage.getUrl() }}">

                </div>

            {% endif %}

        {% set image = block.image.first() %}

            {% if image %}

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">

                    <img src="{{ secondImage.getUrl() }}">

                </div>

            </div>

            {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the issue here where you are setting your image variable.

`{% set image = block.image.first() %}`

This should reference the field handle of the asset you are trying to get the url of, so it should be this instead:

`{% set image = block.firstImage.first() %}`

Then where you try and display the image it should be:

`<img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}">`

You would then need to update this for the `secondImage`.

It might be worth mentioning that there is a cleaner way to achieve what you’re after, with just one asset field.

You can upload multiple images to a single asset field, so assuming `firstImage` has two assets attached, your code could be shortened to the following:

```
...
{% elseif block.type == "imageDouble" %}

 {# this has two assets attached #}
 {% set images = block.firstImage %}

 {% if images and images|length %}

  <div class="row imageDouble detail">

    {# Loop through the images #}
    {% for image in images %}

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}">
      </div>

    {% endfor %}

  </div>

 {% endif %}

{% endif %}
...
```

This will help keep your code from repetition and will be easier to maintain in the future :)

Comment: Thanks a million for not only solving my problem but proposing an even cleaner solution!

Comment: Not a problem :) glad it helped you out!